# For Loop Modifiers not returning any value (~t and ~z)

Tags: batch-file

I have a for loop that I am trying to get date/time creation information for.

The simple version of my code looks like this:

```
set home=C:\Temp\dir1

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b %home%\2nd_dir') do echo file info=%%~na %%~ta
```

It turns out this works if I do not include a path to a directory in the `dir` function.

i.e. If I run that from the current directory, I get the name and timestamp.

However, if I put in a directory to search for, I am only getting the name. I have tried every single for modifier, and `~t` and `~z` are the only ones that are not working.

I could use the `forfiles` function to do this also, but the problem is that directory is actually a network path and not on the `C:` drive, so I have to `robocopy` the files from my network path to a local drive to use `forfiles` *(mapping a drive using `net use` or `pushd` will greatly complicate things)*.

I can test this from the command prompt easier.

Does Work

```
for /f %c in ('dir /b') do set ftime=%~tc
```

Doesn't work

```
for /f %c in ('dir /b C:\temp\dir1') do set ftime=%~tc
```

Does work

```
for /f %c in ('dir /b C:\temp\dir1') do set fname=%~nc
```

Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

`dir/b` gets the filename only, so adding a modifier looks into the *current* directory for the filename.

Try

```
pushd yourrequireddirectory
for ...
popd
```

which should return your appropriate results (no doubt *except* ~d and ~p)

Comment: That would normally work, this for loop is actually nested within another for loop. So it actually looks more like this:

for /f in (command) do (command2) & for /f in (command2) do (command3)

Kind of hard to express without throwing in a ton of details, but I don't think you can do a pushd/popd within a nested for loop like that.

I have been able to get the date and time stamp, so I can my program works, but I need to copy a ton of directories from a network path to a local directory to run that forfiles command and return the date and time.

but you are right, the /b won't help

Comment: There's no reason `pushd/popd` won't work within a loop. Please include this extra detail in your question, with examples if possible.

Comment: Thanks Magoo. Looks like you were right about using pushd/popd in nested for loops. The last time I tried it, it failed because of a syntax error on my behalf (ie typing in "&pushd" instead of "& pushd").

Anyway, not this works since I don't have to use a "dir C;\lots of directory stuff here", I can just pushd right to that directory then use the dir command.

Appreciate the help!